# Creating a class that has_one other class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run the following test:

```
describe "Ghost pages" do
  subject { page }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    user.save
  end
  describe "for signed-in user" do
    before do
      sign_in user
    end
    describe "trying to view his own ghost" do
      before do
        visit ghost_path(user.ghost)
      end
      it { should have_title('Ghost') }
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error, and I can't identify the cause:

Failure/Error: visit ghost_path(user.ghost)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:

Couldn't find Ghost with id=429

./app/controllers/ghosts_controller.rb:48:in `correct_ghost'

Each user has_one ghost. The ghost is created automatically when a user signs up and is created (self.create_ghost). Perhaps the ghost is not being saved correctly somehow?

The relevant bits of code are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ghost, dependent: :destroy
  before_create :create_remember_token
  before_save do
    email.downcase!
    self.create_ghost
  end
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end

class Ghost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :non_signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :correct_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,         only: :destroy
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

class GhostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :correct_ghost, only: [:show]
  before_action :correct_destroyer, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :go_away, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  def index
  end
  def edit
  end
  def update
  end
  def show
    @ghost = Ghost.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @ghost = Ghost.new
  end
  def create
    @ghost = current_user.build_ghost(ghost_params)
    if @ghost.save
      flash[:success] = "Ghost successfully created"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Ghost creation failed"
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @ghost = Ghost.find(params[:id])
    @ghost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Ghost deleted, master."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
  private
    def ghost_params
      params.require(:ghost).permit()
    end
    def correct_ghost
      @ghost = Ghost.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless (current_user.id == @ghost.user_id)
    end
    def correct_destroyer
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
    def go_away
      redirect_to(root_url)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
  user.save
end
```

When the `before` block is executed `user` returns a newly created User, then you call `save` on it. Thus the `before_save` callback will be run twice. When I run that part of your code I see:

```
 Failed to remove the existing associated ghost. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

Your results may differ. In any case, you don't want to create two ghosts.

You could change your callback to avoid creating a ghost when one exists:

```
before_save do
  create_ghost unless ghost
end
```

But it may be preferable to use `before_create` instead, since you only want to create the ghost once.

```
before_create do
  create_ghost
end
```

Comment: I removed the before do user.save from the spec, because as you say, let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } has already saved the user. I also changed the before_save self.create ghost to an after_save (following aledalgrande's answer). At this point the test still failed. Finally, I added unless ghost like you suggested: self.create_ghost unless ghost. Now the test passes. That's great, but it means at some point it's trying to create a ghost when one already exists. Since the before do user.save spec code is gone, when is it trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `Ghost` before its `User` is saved, so the user has no id and the validation on ghost fails. Move it to the `after_save` callback:

```
after_save do
  self.create_ghost
end
```

It also semantically makes sense that a ghost object, which cannot exist without a user object according to your code `dependent: :destroy`, would be created after its user.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the change, but I'm still getting exactly the same error. (I did rake test:prepare)

Comment: See zetetic comment below, a combination of this answer and his have done the trick.